# Textview text length increases grid item height

Tags: android

In my gridview item has textview. When that text length is high, grid item automatically increases grid item height. When text length is overflow grid item width can we show something like three dots and keep all grid items size similar?

Comment: paste your code so people can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
<TextView 
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="4"
android:minLines="1"


              />
```

Comment: This is working. But is there any method to notify there's more text available. Something like three dots

Comment: Found the most suitable answer for my problem : android:singleLine="true"